# Как правильнее делать CRUD?

Tags: php, шаблоны-проектирования

Раньше я всегда совмещал создание и редактирование модели в одном методе, примерно так:

```
public function actionSave($id = null) {
    $model = $id ? $this->findOneOrFail($id) : new Article();

    if ($model->load(\Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate() && $model->save(false)) {
        \Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Сохранено');
        return $this->redirect(['article/list']);
    }

    return $this->render('form', ['model' => $model]);
}
```

Недавно услышал что это не SOLIDно... И типа надо делать отдельный GET метод получения формы, а сохранение и редактирование толи по разным методам, толи в один метод store... Вот хочется услышать объективное мнение как правильно. Нафига дублировать столько кода в угоду паттернам? Когда можно все в один метод залить и будет красиво.

Кстати, еще вопрос, почему метод со списком моделей называют index? Логичнее же list. А метод удаления во многих примерах destroy, хотя казалось бы delete...

Comment: index, create, store, show, update, delete. Если API, то index, store, update, delete. Вы создаете метод с названием `actionSave` (тупая приписка от Yii c action, ну да ладно), при таком методе подразуемвается, что Вы будете только сохранять. На деле же у вас идет смешение логики, то есть то ли сохранение, то ли вывод формы. Плюс `save` у Вас `POST`, а форма выводится по `GET`. Но в такой логике у Вас всё `POST`, что тоже уже неправильно. По ссылкам же при любом раскладе у Вас их две, просто так Вы их объединяете условностью отсутствия параметра.

Comment: @VladimirGonchar а чего плохого то? Зачем городить несколько методов если в них код будет дублироваться? Просто для меня куда приоритетнее принцип DRY, чем какие-то паттерны.

Comment: А с чего бы он дублировался? У Вас тут наоборот сейчас идет месиво в одном методе, когда логика подразумевает разделение на 2. И потом, если у Вас что-то где-то дублируется, то по DRY Вы должны это вынести в отдельные методы (через те же сервисы)

Comment: @VladimirGonchar а с того что все что после строки с нахождением/созданием модели будет одинаково и в создании и в обновлении.

Comment: С чего бы? Вы каждый раз всю строку перезатираете и сохраняете заново? Тогда поздравляю, у Вас излишняя нагрузка) Окей, может в классическом приложении это и буде работать, но при переходе в API, тут уже так прокатывать не будет. Если я отправлю в update только 2 свойства из 20, я должен обновить только их, а не всё вместе взятое.

Comment: Тут уже, конечно, вопросы к Yii, который по определению делает всё некрасиво))

Comment: @VladimirGonchar AR в Yii2 позаботится об этом. Оно проверяет какие свойства изменились и обновляет в базе только их. Для того и существуют ORM чтобы иметь один метод save, а не писать отдельные insert/update.

Comment: @VladimirGonchar вы еще скажите что вьюхи разные используете)))) Поля то одни и те же...

Comment: `index` это типа "содержание/указатель" в книгах, когда в конце у вас написано что и на какой странице, имхо, оттуда пошло такое наименование метода в принципе в любых фреймворках.

Comment: @VladimirGonchar вопрос то вроде про создание и обновление, это всегда POST/PUT. А не про вывод get-пустой формы.

Comment: @teran В любом случае логика может (и должна быть) разная на сохранение новой записи и редактирование текущей. Как минимум, что в нормальном вебе нет понятия POST на обновление (это только в PHP так, и то не везде, в том же Laravel нормально обрабатывается).

Comment: @ПЭХАПЭШНИК Я уже давно не использую шаблонизацию на сервере, я на Vue/Nuxt отдельно клиент пишу, и тут как раз эта проблема обозначенная очень заметна, потому что методы разные, роуты разные. Если в Вашем случае удобно - нет проблем, используйте. Не нужно пытаться насильно заставлять себя делать по-другому. Когда дойдете до осознания, что методы смешивать плохо, то сразу всё встанет на свои места.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше делать каждый метод отдельно, как вы в принципе сейчас можете увидеть в GII.

Это делается, потому что

- код в дальнейшем легче доработать
- нет 100500 if-ов
- нет даже намёка на какую-то совмещенную логику.

Всё по полочкам, ищи логику ровно в нужном методе, это круто.

Касательно совмещёнки, это плохой тон, такая практика целенаправленно используется только если

- делать что-то надо очень быстро, и будет рефакторинг
- нет уверенности, что это нужный функционал, сказали "давайте потестим, и быро там, нам архитектура не нужна"
- это прототип, который надо только вам.

Вы же в реальной жизни, например, не смешиваете алкоголь по чём зря, мотивируя это как `а какая разница то? в желудке же перемешается`. Ну а если вам ещё и лекарство пить, так мб тогда и лекарство в общую тару, да, перемешается же?

Это классный подход, как кажется сначала, и классный он на каких-то дешёвых веб студиях, где надо быстро, и за 5 мин. В продукте за такое могут(и будут в 99% случаев) "бить по рукам"

---

upd, кстати, а вот задумайтесь: чем плох смешанный алкоголь?

Правильно, тем что чтобы настало "бо-бо", нужно гораздо меньше выпить, и "бо-бо" будет более жесткое, чем если просто пить что-то одно по градусу.

Так же и в разработке: гавнокод делает "бо-бо"(в нашем случае тех.долг) всегда. Гавнокод в квадрате только усугубляет положение проекта, и зачастую приводит к тому, что правка чего-то лёгенького ВСЕГДА будет огромной, титанически сложной задачей

Comment: Понимаете, я столкнулся с этой штукой когда перешел с Yii на Laravel. И понял что подход к обработке форм там кардинально отличается. В Laravel при POST запросе делается валидация (как и в Yii), но потом кидается исключение с ошибками валидации, после чего происходит редирект на страницу с которой была отправлена форма, и самое главное - в сессии передаются ошибки и данные которые заполнялись, таким образом их можно отрендерить во вьюхе. В Yii же все куда проще - при POST запросе никуда не редиректит, а после валидации ошибки сразу прокидываются во вьюху, рендерятся и отдаются.

Comment: Так вот в Yii получается нет возможности сделать в разных действиях (если только не реализовывать вручную такую же фишку с сессией и редиректом).

Comment: можно, причём по-разному. Можно и на фронте, можно и на бэке. читайте доки, особенно обратите внимание на Html хелпер.

Comment: ваши пассажи про алкоголь это плохая аналогия. По сути аналогией тут будет "взять первый стакан для первой порции" а для второй и последющей использовать другой стакан. В целом за стиль изложения в духе "с бомжами в подъезде обсудили" ловите минус. на СО же обычно пишут нормальным грамотным языком без жаргонизмов тем более отдающих нецензурщиной.

Comment: @AlexKhonko я разрабатывал на Yii не один год, но такого способа не знаю. Можете конкретно сказать что из Html хелпера тут может помочь? Это ведь совсем другой способ обработки форм.

Comment: @ПЭХАПЭШНИК "Так вот в Yii получается нет возможности сделать в разных действиях" --- бред. у формы есть validateUrl который можно указать для валидации.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский это для аяксовой валидации. Сомнительная штука. И это совсем не про обычную отправку формы. При сохранении ее все равно надо валидировать.

Comment: @teran за слово "говнокод" ещё можно было бы ататшечки сделать, но вот за сравнение с выпивкой с алкоголем....вполне себе. Показать что-то выходя из профессиональныфх рамок и донести мысль на простых обыденных вещах - вполне себе нормально